# how to bypass the username default insert in django?

Tags: python, django, database, authentication, model

Currently having django 1.9

Using it's own built-in user model.
I changed the way of login can either use username/email but when registering, I don't want username to be used.

When I start saving it'll give me error of `UNIQUE constraint failed: auth_user.username` which I know it's because it must be entered.

Is there a way to easily bypass it?

Comment: Sounds more like an issue of using blank usernames colliding against the `UNIQUE` constraint. Did you try generating dummy usernames so that you won't have a unique conflict?

Comment: @Hybrid yes I tried generate dummy username, but I figured maybe I should just by pass it by silently saving the username as email.